# Why I got undefined variable?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have class with property:

```
public requestLoadPersonal: Personal[] = [];
```

And one method:

```
private filterByGender(selectedValue: any): void {
    console.log(this.requestLoadPersonal);
    this.requestLoadPersonal = this.requestLoadPersonal.filter(
      (p: Personal) => {
        return selectedValue ? p.gender == selectedValue : true;
      }
    );
  }
```

In constructor of class I have:

```
 public filterFn = {
    name: this.filterByGender
 }
```

Why when I call function `this.filterByGender` from object `filterFn` by key. I got undefined message, why variable `this.requestLoadPersonal` is not available inside:

`console.log(this.requestLoadPersonal);` ?

Calling as:

```
 this.filterFn['name']({...});
```

I tried to bind variable:

```
 this.filterFn['name']({...}).bind(this.requestLoadPersonal);
```

Comment: Did you try using arrow functions ?

Comment: No it is trivial function in object

Comment: maybe you should bind just `this`?

Comment: Can you show your constructor? Also, you should write the exact error message: undefined what?

Comment: Sure:  `constructor() { this.filterFn = {
    name: this.filterByName }; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you should bind the function to `this` like this:

```
constructor() { this.filterFn = { name: this.filterByName.bind(this) }; }
```

Because just `{name: this.filterByName}` loses the `this` context, i.e.
`filterByName` has `this` context of some other instance.

However, I'd suggest you simplify everything and make it more straight-forward. Currently it's complex and thus, error-prone.

Comment: Sure, I tried: `this.filterFn = {
      name: this.filterByName.bind(this.requestLoadPersonal)}`. It does not work still

Comment: No, you should bind `this`, not `this.requestLoadPersonal`

Comment: I tried and `this` I get still undefined inside function

Comment: @OPV Oh, OK, congrats :) I would simplify you code, if I were you.

Comment: @dince12 You used it frequently, but don't fully understand why?